# While loop and for statement

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to build an online reading test for my students. I currently have two tables in my database : 'student' and 'questions'. In 'student', I have a row for each student which containts it's name, group number and answers to the questions. Questions cols are called question[1], question [2], and so on.

In 'questions', I have 4 cols : ID, 'first', 'chapter' and 'question'. 'first' is a true/false field, if it is the first question to a chapter its value is 1. I call those with a while loop.

```
echo '<ol>';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `question`");
while($row_q = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
if($row_q['first']==1){
echo '<h2>Chapter '.$row_q['chapter'].'</h2><br>';
}
echo '<li>';
echo $row_q['question'];
echo '</li>';
echo '<br>';
}
echo '</ol>';
```

It echoes beautifuly. Now, I'm trying to put an input field under each question so the student can give an answer and submit it at the end of the page. How can I do this? I tried using a for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) statement since I want each field to be named with a different number, but no matter where I insert it, I either end up with a bunch of identical fields next to each other or my questions echoed over and over again.

I'm open to all suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: also, you should't need the `echo '<br>';`. `<li>` tags display as blocks and if you want more padding you should do this with css: `<style> li {padding:5px 0px;}</style>`

Comment: @sarah ok there are 2 things i want to ask 1st you want to submit more than one ans to a question (like 4 ans to question 1) or only one ans to a question and close the ans field for users?
2nd are you using ajex to submit the form?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no need to do a for loop, you're already in a loop :) just set a variable called question number and increment it in the while loop.

```
$question_number =1;

echo '<ol>';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `question`");
while($row_q = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if($row_q['first']==1){
        echo '<h2>Chapter '.$row_q['chapter'].'</h2><br>';
    }
    echo '<li>';
    echo "<label>$question_number".$row_q['question']."</label>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='$row_q[\'ID\']'></input>";
    echo '</li>';
    echo '<br>';

    $question_number++; 
}
echo '</ol>';
```

Comment: Didn't think I could icrease it directly in my loop... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> echo '<input name="answer[' . htmlspecialchars($row_q['ID']) . ']" type="text" value="" />';

under the question text... Then in PHP var_dump($_REQUEST) to see the answers...

EDIT:

For displaying the saved answer, you'll want to do something like this:

```
echo '<input name="answer_' . $idx . '" type="text" ' .
  value="' . htmlspecialchars($student_row["answer_$idx"]) . '" />';
```

and maintain a counter $idx as you loop...

That's if your answer are laid out flat in the student table per your description and the answer value columns are named "answer_1" etc.

If the answers are normalized in a separate table, you can join the tables together:

```
select * from question q left join answer a on a.question_id = q.question_id and
  a.student_id = <current student id>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! 

Now, I'd like the value to be what is inside the database for that particular question, so the student can come back to the form at some point and change his answer. In my db, answer cols are displayed as answer[1], answer[2]...

<code>    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `eleve`");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo '<input name="answer[' . htmlspecialchars($row_q['ID']) . ']" type="text" value="' . $row['question[]'] . '" />';</code>

I know something is wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing the field for answer[1], answer[2]... Looks like I'm missing a quote or something. 

`value="' . $row['answer'][$idx]. '"`

I get this notice. Notice: Undefined index: answer

Comment: try `$row["answer[$idx]"]`. you can var_dump($row) to see exactly what the column name is

Comment: Double quotes was the answer. Thanks again!